# convert String MAC address to char[6] in C

Tags: c

```
char mac[] = "00:13:a9:1f:b0:88";
int a[6];
sscanf(mac, "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", &a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3], &a[4], 
&a[5]);
```

generally, it worked. But when mac contains something like "0(x)" it breaks

for example

```
char mac[] = "01:13:a9:1f:b0:88"; // 01 became 00 in above code
```

any trick?

---

**This due to memory issues which caused by other parts of the program**

**Keeping here for inspiration **

Comment: It works fine, look at https://ideone.com/ZPvXVp

Comment: The code you posted works, `01` becomes `1` or `0x01` and gets written into `a[0]`.

Comment: Your question title doesn't match the question. `char[6]` should be  `int[6]`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and expected vs. actual output.

Comment: Did you google for *any* duplicates? This gets asked if not once per week then at least once a month

Answer (score 1):

sscanf knows to ignore leading zeros.

I've tried your code on windows with visual studio, and on linux with gcc and it works fine. I suggest you check again your results, as your program seems to work fine.

if you want your 'a' array be printed the same as the input use printf with **%02x** modifier

Comment: "`sscanf` knows to ignore leading zeros" is true with the `%x` and `%d` format specifiers but not with `%i`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. for %i, leading zero gives different behavior. here is a cite from the sscanf man page: %i Matches an optionally signed integer; the next pointer must be a pointer to int. The integer is read in base 16 if it begins with 0x or 0X, in base 8 if it begins with 0, and in base 10 otherwise. Only characters that correspond to the base are used.

Answer (score 1):

simple solution:

```
char mac[] = "00-13-a9-1f-b0-88";
int a[6];
sscanf(mac, "%x-%x-%x-%x-%x-%x", &a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3], &a[4], &a[5]);
```

Then copy values of ‘a’ to char array.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. Check this

```
int main()
{
  char mac1[] = "0x2:0x13:0xa9:0x1f:0xb0:0x88";
  char mac2[] = "02:13:a9:1f:b0:88";
  int a[6];

  sscanf(mac1, "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", &a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3], &a[4], &a[5]);
  printf("%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]);

  sscanf(mac2, "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", &a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3], &a[4], &a[5]);
  printf("%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]);
}
```

Output:

```
02:13:a9:1f:b0:88
02:13:a9:1f:b0:88
```